# Scope not working in dialog login URL Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-login

I am trying to implement login by url like: https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?response_type=code&client_secret=xxx&grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=xxx&redirect_uri=xxx&scope=email pages_manage_metadata pages_messaging pages_read_engagement pages_read_user_content pages_show_list.

But dialog seems not working like scope in URL. It just allow me for name and avatar.
Thanks for helping me!

Comment: Did you properly URL-encode this parameter value - considering that is contains lots of spaces?

Comment: The documentation says that scope can be either a space or comma separated list - I would really recommend to use the latter.

Comment: I already used comma, but it still not working. Anyway, with my account facebook (role admin in facebook app developer ) work perfectly, but other account cant.

Comment: I very confusing if I miss some configuration. All permission about page is "Standard Access".

Comment: You still need to go through app review, before users without a role in your app can be asked for any permissions that require review. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-review

Comment: Thanks for your supporting! I have already done request for app review and still waiting.